# Where to find business unit settings?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to find out what business units exist when you're an admin in a child business unit? I don't see any settings for seeing more business units configuration or even a way to add myself to other business units. Is that only a possibility if you're created in the parent account? Any insight helps, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't in a Parent BU you would not be able to see other child BU. Permissions to additional child BU would happen from the parent BU. Your admin at the Parent BU can add your user to additional BU [if needed.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_business_units.htm&type=5)

> Manage user roles for the business unit, view users who have access to the business unit, and define filter criteria for subscribers. Business units are available in Enterprise and Enterprise 2.0 accounts.